# "If ​there is a god please help me"

Tags: conditionals

What​ conditional is this​ ​sentence?

> If ​there is a god please help me.

Is​ it​ *real​* conditional?

This explanation was taken from a website called *[VOA Learning English](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-introducing-conditionals/2778457.html#:%7E:text=Basically%2C%20when%20A%20happens%2C%20B,an%20umbrella%20if%20it%20rains.%22)*

> The present real conditional is the most basic kind of conditional. Basically, when A happens, B happens.
>
> Here's an example of a present real conditional:
>
> "If it **rains**, I **bring** an umbrella."

But shouldn't it​ be​ an *unreal* conditional?

Is there a​ difference in meaning if​ I use *were*: "If there were a god" in​stead​ of​ "is"?

Comment: Recast your sentence (which is not very idiomatic any way you analyze it) without the dummy subject *there* to better understand: *If a god exists, [then] please help me.* It's a kind of pseudo-conditional, like: *If you're hungry, [then] there's food in the pantry.* The food is already in the pantry whether you're hungry or not — no cause and effect.

Comment: *If anybody's home, open the door.*  In practical situations the if-clause there is a shout out, a form of indirect address.

Answer (score 9):

If you say "if there were a God", you are revealing that you do not believe there is a God. Also unreal conditional cannot be combined with an imperative mood verb, which

> makes direct commands and requests ([Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/imperative-mood-grammar-1691151)).

I mean, if the situation is unreal, why bother give the command or make the request?

Imperative can be used when the speaker believes the situation is likely to happen. [Grammaring](https://www.grammaring.com/imperatives-in-the-first-conditional#:%7E:text=Imperatives%20can%20be%20used%20to,play%20football%20with%20your%20friends.) explains:

> Imperatives can be used to replace either clause of the [first conditional](https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/1cond):
>
> - If you've done the dishes, please ***mop*** the floor.(1)
> - ***Tidy*** up your room, and you can go out to play football with your friends.(2)

The first sentence is more similar to your example. I understand your sentence as  meaning:

> If you are there, God, please help me.

Comment: Beautifully explained.

Comment: 'If A is true, then, X, please do B' is hardly comparable to 'There may be an X. If there is: X, please do B'. The listener is known to exist and be listening in (1).

Comment: "If the patient were to have taken arsenic, he would be showing exactly the same symptoms that he is now showing" <-- The use of *were* does NOT entail that the speaker thinks that the situation in the *if*-clause is not true!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Came across this sentence recently and a self-styled authority on grammar suggested that it should be **weren't** instead of **wasn't** in the sentence. I would like to know your thoughts. The sentence is: "[_Communist Party_?] _It's hard to believe Mr. Trump would make these accusations if Ms. Chao **wasn't** ethnic Chinese._

Comment: So​ real​ conditional​ is used​ when​ you​ say​ something you​ belive it​ is​ real? can​  i​ say​ "If​ i​ am rich i​ will buy a​ ​house"?

Comment: When you think it is likely to happen (and it probably will). It is more idiomatic to say in this case, _**When** I am rich, I will buy a house_.

Comment: @user405662 Never trust self-styled authorities on grammar! The verb forms in the original sentence are fine. :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That's what I thought were the correct verb forms. But because he's christened himself after a bona fide authority on grammar, I began to doubt my instinct. Lol. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Why​ cant​ i​ use​ imperative with​ unreal​ situations? If​ i​ didnt​ expect someone to​ know​ how​ to​ do​ something​ can​ i​ say​  if​ you knew it​ then​ do​ it?